# Add a filter to a different custom plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, filters, content

Someone has built a custom plugin that adds a textarea on the admin/edit page, and a div on the pub page. I no longer have access to the person who built the custom plugin.

I have created a filter for the main page content by doing something like this:

```
function getHappy($content) { //goofy example
    str_replace(":)", "=^..^=", $content);
    return (is_single()) ? $content : $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'getHappy');
```

Where `the_content` is the hook for the main page content. How can I go about finding out what the hook for a plugin is? If it doesn't have one, is there a way to add one?

The problem is I am pulling live content with the filter, which means I cannot retrieve the data stored by the plugin, then alter it. It needs to be a 'live' filter.

Am I looking at this the wrong way? In this case is `the_content` not even used, but `$content` is? If it is the latter, is it as simple as finding the variable that holds the custom content?

These may be broad questions, but I hope the answer is fairly simple.

I am trying to do this in a way that won't break every time I update WP.

Cheers, Bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was simple, though there may be a better way of dealing with it.

In the custom_display.php of the custom theme display page.

`apply_filters ( 'the_content' , $theContentVar);`

This may not be best practice, but it works. Hope it helps someone else...